# Use Flask Sockets request/ws out of context

Tags: sockets, flask, request, python-decorators, flask-sockets

I would like to be able to use a Flask request out of context.

I realise since Flask 0.10 there is a decorator(`@copy_current_request_context`) available to do that, and this is how I am using that decorator to try and modify [flask-socket](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets/blob/master/flask_sockets.py) . Specifically the `@socket.route`  decorator which is part of **flask-sockets**:

```
def route(self, rule, request, **options):

    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
        @copy_current_request_context
        def do_some_work():
            env = request.environ['wsgi.websocket']
            self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f,env, **options)
        gevent.spawn(do_some_work)
        return f
    return decorator
```

Although the error this produces does make sense to me - I am assuming there's a way to do what I want.:

```
RuntimeError: This decorator can only be used at local scopes when a   
request context is on the stack.  For instance within view functions.
```

I tried passing the request into the decorator, but that didn't work.

To give a little more context, I am trying to add the `request.environ['wsgi.websocket']` to a dict inside the Sockets object to be able to access the `ws` variable (which I understand to be the request environment).

On a higher level, I'd like the ability to do `ws.send()` from somewhere other than the `@route` function or view - perhaps another thread that has access to the socket object instance.

I've done something similar with **Socket-IO** - where the `socketio` object is all you need to be able to `send()` and `recieve()` data - however with Sockets it seems you need the ws object, which is the `request.environ['wsgi.websocket']`